# FALLO INSERT PHP con AJAX (No INSERTA)

Tags: php, sql, ajax, mysqli, insert

Intento ejecutar la siguiente consulta: y me da error:

--

```
  function crearProducto() {

    $con = getConn();

    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $descripcion_pagina = $_POST['descripcion_pagina'];
    $canonical = $_POST['canonical'];
    $link_prod = $_POST['link_prod'];
    $h1 = $_POST['h1'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $ref = $_POST['ref'];
    $precio = $_POST['precio'];
    $precio_oferta = $_POST['precio_oferta'];
    $stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $visible = $_POST['visible'];
    $envio = $_POST['envio'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $img_princip = $_POST['img_princip'];
    $alt_img_princip = $_POST['alt_img_princip'];

    // CREAR ARRAY CON LA IMÁGEN, ASÍ GUARDAR URL Y ALT:

    $img = array(
        "url" => $img_princip,
        "alt" => $alt_img_princip
    );

    $query = 'INSERT INTO bt_productos (categoria, url, title, description, canonical, afiliado, h1, nombre, ref, precio, precio_oferta, stock, visible, envio, descripcion) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

    if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("issssssssddiiss", $categoria, $url, $title, $descripcion_pagina, $canonical, $link_prod, $h1, $nombre, $ref, $precio, $precio_oferta, $stock, $visible, $envio, $descripcion);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == true) {
            $resultado = 1;
        }

     }

    return $resultado;

  }
```

Además, mando desde aquí el ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/api.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      categoria: categoria,
      url: url,
      title: title,
      descripcion_pagina: descripcion_pagina,
      canonical: canonical,
      link_prod: link_prod,
      h1: h1,
      nombre: nombre,
      ref: ref,
      precio: precio,
      precio_oferta: precio_oferta,
      stock: stock,
      visible: visible,
      envio: envio,
      descripcion: descripcion,
      img_princip: img_princip,
      alt_img_princip: alt_img_princip,
      action: action
    },
    success: function(e) {
      console.log(e);

    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert('fail');
    }
```

** Añadir, que si que pasa por el success.

No consigo localizar el error, pero no me inserta el producto, sin embargo, otras consultas si me funcionan. (la conexión es correcta).

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revise en el navegador, en la pestaña Network, la petición que realiza, Luego en la ventana Response, obtiene algún mensaje de error o algo ?

Comment: No obtengo ningún mensaje de error, y al parecer la consulta es correcta

Comment: ¿Pero en el `success` te muestra el `1` que imprimes desde el servidor? Esto: `if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == true) {` es mejor ponerlo así: `if ($con->affected_rows > 0) {
            $resultado = 1;
        } else { $resultado= "Error: ".$stmt->error;}  $stmt->close();` O sea, preguntar si es mayor que `0` es más coherente. Además cerrar `$stmt` luego, imprimir un mensaje de error e igualar todo el código al estilo orientado a objetos, pues estás mezclando estilos. Prueba así y dinos el resultado.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, muchas gracias por tu consejo para localizar correctamente el error. Al parecer, estaba utilizando en el campo descripción, un textarea con el complemento CKEDITOR, y hay que recoger los datos de otra forma para que la consulta sea correcta. Muchísimas gracias.